# Memory Error & AttributeError in Python when move OpenCV's frame to Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I trying to move OpenCV's frame to Tkinter

Code Following...

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from cv2 import cv2
```

To show the video

```
class CamWindow:
    def __init__(self, window, title:str, cam_plug = 0, delay = 15):

        self.delay = delay

        self.window = window

        self.title = title
        self.window.title(self.title)

        self.cam = MyVideoCapture(cam_plug)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width = self.cam.width, height = self.cam.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.photoButton = tk.Button(self.window, text="SnapShot", width=30, command=self.shot)
        self.photoButton.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, expand=True)
        self.update()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def shot(self):
        ret, frame = self.cam.getPic()
        if ret:
            cv2.imwrite(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")+".jpg", cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))

    def update(self):
        ret, frame = self.cam.getPic()
        if ret:
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(frame))
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tk.NW)
        self.window.after(self.delay, self.update())
```

```
class MyVideoCapture:
    def __init__(self, cam_plug = 0):
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_plug, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        if not self.cam.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("cannot open camera at %d", cam_plug)
        self.width = self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.height = self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

    def getPic(self):
        if self.cam.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.cam.read()
            if ret:
                return ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            else:
                return ret, None
        else:
            return None, None

    def __del__(self):
        if self.cam.isOpened:
            self.cam.release()
```

the terminal shows memory error, but everything seems to make sense.

and also I met "Attributeerror: 'photoimage' object has no attribute '_photoimage__photo'"
if there's any method or codes having problems please tell me as well
==========================edit===========================

my main file.py is:

```
from module.UI import CamWindow

def main():
    CamWindow(tk.Tk(), title = "camera window", delay = 30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is `frame` in the line `self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(frame))`?  It is undefined when the line is executed.

Comment: Sorry wrong line, it should be inside the if in method update

Comment: Your code works fine after changing `self.window.after(self.delay, self.update())` to `self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)`